How to quit canonical-livepatch to allow update (annoying reminder)
since upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 I am again and again seeing a notification pop-up window asking me to quit canonical-livepatch because an update is available.
Thing is, I am not using Ubuntu Pro Livepatch, it's switched off.
So how do I "quit" canonical-livepatch or maybe much better, get rid of it?

How to stop Livepatch due to a pending update, install the update, and restart Livepatch:
sudo snap stop canonical-livepatch
  // Wait a few seconds

sudo snap refresh 
  // Some users may get a response a refresh is already in progress
  // That's okay

sudo snap start canonical-livepatch

How to "get rid" of Livepatch for most users:
sudo snap remove canonical-livepatch

